# How to change image src, when onclick and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When onclick ".swiper-slide", addClass('selected')

I could change the img src when onclick svg-img1 , 2 , 3

But I want a image coming back to default img src. when I click other swiper-slide.

```js
$('.swiper-slide').on('click', function() {
    $('.swiper-slide').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#swi-image1').on({
     'click':function() {
      if($('#svg-img1').hasClass("selected")) {
       $('#svg-img1').attr('src','/img/front/photos-white.svg');
   } else {
       $('#svg-img1').attr('src','/img/front/photos.svg');
   }
  }
 });

 $('#swi-image2').on({
  'click':function() {
   $('#svg-img2').attr('src','/img/front/youtube-white.svg');
  }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container pt-2 pb-4" id="contents-swiper">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide" id="swi-img1"><img src="/img/front/photos.svg" id="svg-img1">card</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide" id="swi-img2"><img src="/img/front/youtube.svg" id="svg-img2">youtube</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide" id="swi-img3"><img src="/img/front/microphone.svg" id="svg-img3">cast</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: default]

[image: when onclick the div swiper-slide]

[image: when onclick other div swiper-slide]

Comment: You have to add jQuery to your code snippet. Currently, '$' is not defined.

Comment: Include any one svg code too

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
$('.swiper-slide').on('click', function(){
  $('.swiper-slide').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  if($('#swi-img1').hasClass("selected")){
    $('#svg-img1').attr('src','/img/front/photos-white.svg');
  }else{
    $('#svg-img1').attr('src','/img/front/photos.svg');
  }
  
  if($('#swi-img2').hasClass("selected")){
    $('#svg-img2').attr('src','/img/front/youtube-white.svg');
  } else {
    $('#svg-img2').attr('src','/img/front/youtube.svg');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container pt-2 pb-4" id="contents-swiper">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide" id="swi-img1"><img src="/img/front/photos.svg" id="svg-img1">card</div>
    
  <div class="swiper-slide" id="swi-img2"><img src="/img/front/youtube.svg" id="svg-img2">youtube</div>
    
  <div class="swiper-slide" id="swi-img3"><img src="/img/front/microphone.svg" id="svg-img3">cast</div>
 </div>
</div>
```